# What are the alternatives to Google Glass?

Tags: wearable-technology

Since Google announced that it would stop producing the [Google Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Glass) technology, are there any alternatives on the market?

My requirements are:

- modest design,
- good open-source API/SDK with the community support,
- built-in camera,
- display,
- integration with mobile smart apps

Comment: Do you have a weight requirement / preference? From my (admittedly limited) experience wearing Glass it's on the heavy side, and is somewhat uncomfortable to wear for long stretches.

Comment: @Undo No weight requirement, as I'm new into this and I was disappointed that I haven't got tested Google Glass, so I would be happy that anything would be similar there, as I heard some companies planned to do some competition to it. In case there are too many choices, I could narrow it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like theres a consumer version out yet, but [**Sony SmartEyeglass**](http://developer.sonymobile.com/products/smarteyeglass/) looks promising.

- Has a better design than Google Glass (In my opinion)
- Has a SDK (Can't comment on whether it's "good" or not, as I never used it)
- Built-in 3MP camera
- Not 100% sure about integration with mobile apps, but it does say that it supports devices running Android 4.4 and above

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has been discontinued. I am hoping that someone will post another.

In the meantime, there are a few d.i.y projects floating about, like [this one](https://hackaday.io/project/166218-diy-smartglasses-with-the-raspberry-pi) on Hackaday.

Or [Raspberry Pi Smart Glasses](https://buzzon.live/67161-raspberry-pi-smart-glasses/)

Hackaday also have a list [glasses-based projects](https://www.hackster.io/search?i=projects&q=glasses), which might be of interest.

[Build Your Own Open-Source AR Headset For Under $80](https://vrscout.com/news/build-your-own-open-source-ar-headset/)

[DIY E.D.I.T.H. Glasses #WearableWednesday](https://blog.adafruit.com/2021/07/21/diy-e-d-i-t-h-glasses-wearablewednesday/)

[DIY Wearable Pi with Near-Eye Video Glasses](https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-wearable-pi-near-eye-kopin-video-glasses) from AdaFruit.

[Diy Smart Glasses Raspberry Pi 2021](https://mbc-web.org/diy-smart-glasses-raspberry-pi/)

No doubt there are more, but I am not sure if OP (who hasn't logged in in two years) would accept a DIY solution. But, hopefully, some of this will help someone.