# Are there any budget programmable smart glasses for DIY projects?

Tags: development, displays, portable, wearable-technology, smart-device

I am looking for some smart glasses to do some college project but most of them are way too costly.

These are my requirements,

1. it should have a colored display.
2. bluetooth/wifi connectivity
3. camera
4. some way to record input, either via touch gestures or motion gestures.
5. some memory (512 mb, 1gb, 2gb, or 4gb). (Completely optional feature).
6. battery

What I am going to do is, connect the smart glass with some device, either pc or smart phone where all the processing will take place, and use smart glasses as input/output device. The only role of smart glass is to get input and display output. I don't need some standalone device as I am always going to connect it with some device.

I am not looking for bulky headset, just small device which can fit on glasses would be great.

Comment: What would the 2 to 4 Gb be used for? Video in/out buffers?

Comment: @AlexisWilke either store/run some video or some application.

Comment: Did you find anything yet?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica nothing much. Only way I found is to 3d print the glasses and use raspberry pi pico to connect to any device wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

Copied form my answer to [What are the alternatives to Google Glass?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/347/what-are-the-alternatives-to-google-glass) ...

There are a few d.i.y projects floating about, like [this one](https://hackaday.io/project/166218-diy-smartglasses-with-the-raspberry-pi) on Hackaday.

Or [Raspberry Pi Smart Glasses](https://buzzon.live/67161-raspberry-pi-smart-glasses/)

Hackaday also have a list [glasses-based projects](https://www.hackster.io/search?i=projects&q=glasses), which might be of interest.

[Build Your Own Open-Source AR Headset For Under $80](https://vrscout.com/news/build-your-own-open-source-ar-headset/)

[DIY E.D.I.T.H. Glasses #WearableWednesday](https://blog.adafruit.com/2021/07/21/diy-e-d-i-t-h-glasses-wearablewednesday/)

[DIY Wearable Pi with Near-Eye Video Glasses](https://learn.adafruit.com/diy-wearable-pi-near-eye-kopin-video-glasses) from AdaFruit.

[Diy Smart Glasses Raspberry Pi 2021](https://mbc-web.org/diy-smart-glasses-raspberry-pi/)